# Create Vaadin project without Vaadin plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, vaadin

Is it possible to create a Vaadin project in Eclipse without installing the Vaadin plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

just use the maven build system for this.
You will then have to open the maven project in eclipse, there are tutorials for this as well.

[How to create a maven vaadin project](https://vaadin.com/framework/get-started)

```
mvn -B archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application \
-DarchetypeVersion=8.3.0 \
-DgroupId=org.test \
-DartifactId=vaadin-app \
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
cd vaadin-app mvn package jetty:run
```

[Available arch types](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/getting-started/getting-started-archetypes.html)

Comment: is it possible with ant

Comment: To clarify, the Vaadin Ltd company has moved away from requiring an IDE plugin. They now rely on the Maven system for downloading and installing dependencies (other libraries needed by Vaadin) and for building/debugging your project. You should invest some time in learning the basics of using Maven. Fortunately that investment will help you long-term as Maven-driven projects are very common in the Java ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

In 11/2020 there is the possibility to configure a sample Vaadin (14) or newer version project based on Spring Boot and download it: https://start.vaadin.com/

You can import that project into Eclipse.

This way the project is not **created** in Eclipse but after these steps you've got a project running in Eclipse.

The web page has multiple example views that can be used as baseline for your development.